# BeautifulSoup4 - python: how to merge two bs4.element.ResultSet and get one single list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have two

```
bs4.element.ResultSet
```

objects.

Let's call them

```
rs1
rs2
```

I want **one result set** (let's call it **rs**) with all the results in resultset.

I also need to figure out:

- whether an array or list or dictionary is better to navigate through a (potentially) big list of results given that each element will consist of an object which is composed of 7 properties of different types
- how to convert the merged resultset to the array/list/dictionary

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `bs4.element.ResultSet` object is a straight-up subclass of `list`. You can use `ResultSet.extend()` to extend one or the other resultset:

```
rs1.extend(rs2)
```

or simply concatenate the two result sets:

```
newlist = rs1 + rs2
```

The latter creates a `list` object with the contents of the two result sets, which means you'll lose the `.source` attribute. Not a great loss, really, seeing as nothing in BeautifulSoup itself uses that attribute.

There are ways to create just the one result set to begin with, rather than concatenate the two. Searches that can find either result type would lead to the results being returned in document source order, rather than back to back.  You can use list arguments to the `find_all()` method, for example:

```
soup.find_all(['a', 'link'], href=True)
```

would find all `a` and `link` elements with a `href` attribute, for example.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually I need to get a list with all the tags whole class is X and the ones whose class is Y. how do I do it?

Comment: @dragonmnl: `soup.find_all(class_=['x', 'y'])` finds elements with either class.